# Insufficient privileges when creating a trigger for a table in another schema

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, triggers, oracle10g

When I try to create a trigger in schema A for a table located in schema B, I get an ora error : insufficient privileges.

What privileges do I need?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

If you are creating the trigger in your schema, you'll need the CREATE TRIGGER privilege.  In order to create the trigger in somebody else's schema, you'll need the CREATE ANY TRIGGER privilege.

[This resource](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/statements_7004.htm) does a very good job of explaining the requirements, and contains more information about triggers (syntax, enabling, disabling, etc).

Comment: You can create a trigger in schema X that fires on an action on a table in schema Y. I think this requires CREATE ANY TRIGGER which is very powerful. Suggest DBA do a 
create trigger user_x.trigger_name before insert on user_y.tab_name begin ... end;
rather than grant CREATE ANY TRIGGER to user_x